# How can I determine if key is an object (twig)?

Tags: symfony, object, twig

I want to determine if my key is an object:

```
  {% for key in columns %}
      {% if key is object %}
        This is an object
      {% else %}
       This in not an object
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

But I get the error message:

> Unknown "object" test.

Comment: What's the value of `columns` ? Do you have an error message a bit more verbose ?

Comment: Twig does not have a built in is_object function/filter.  Perhaps a clue that you might want to rethink your design.  Otherwise, time to learn how to build your very own [twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html).  It is a useful skill to have.

Comment: @gogaz Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unknown "object" test."

Comment: I tried `{% if key == "[object Object]" %}` but this didn't work out to

Comment: @Cerad I will try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your **own Twig extension**. I see you've tagged your question with Symfony so assuming you use Twig in Symfony, you can follow this tutorial:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/twig_extension.html

What you need to do is add new `TwigTest` based on this example:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#tests

You should end up with something like this:

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigTest;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getTests()
    {
        return array(
            new TwigTest('object', array($this, 'isObject')),
        );
    }

    public function isObject($object)
    {
        return is_object($object);
    }
}
```

Code above is not tested, but should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to check if a variable is an **object or a string** :

```
{% if var.id|default('') is not same as ('') %}
```