# How can I find out if my variable is an object or an array with twig?

Tags: arrays, object, twig

I try to find out if my variable is an object or an array:

```
{% if variable is iterable %}It is an array{% else %}it is an object{% endif %}
```

But in cases I get the result:

```
It is an array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the twig `iterable` test has shortcomings, since objects can be iterable as well. PHP has handy functions like `is_array` and `is_object`, however, it is not possible to access regular PHP function in Twig directly. So, we need to write a Twig extension/Test, i.e. add a new `Twig_SimpleTest` to check if an item `is_array`. You can add this test to your app configuration after the general twig bootstrap.

```
$isArray= new Twig_SimpleTest('array', function ($value) {
    return is_array($value);
});
$twig->addTest($isArray);
```

and simply us it like this:

```
{% if var is array%} It is an array
{% else %} It is an object{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can also check this post that shows how to add it similar code as Twig Extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/53681305/8291949

Answer (score 0):

As wp78de said, we can use Twig extension. I've just tried and it works.

For Symfony 6.x, here is the code to check if variable is an array or object

```
<?php
// src/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigTest;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getTests()
    {
        return array(
            //used in Twig template, if var is object/array
            /**
             * Example :
             *  {% if machine_types is array%}
             *      It is an array
                {% else %} It is an object
                {% endif %}
            */
            new TwigTest('object', [$this, 'isObject']),
            new TwigTest('array', [$this, 'isArray']),
            new TwigTest('numeric', [$this, 'isNumeric']),
        );
    }

    public function isObject($object)
    {
        return is_object($object);
    }

    public function isArray($value) {
        return is_array($value);
    }

    public function isNumeric($value)
    {
        return is_numeric($value);
    }
}
```

**Usage in twig template**

```
{% if [] is array%} It is an array
{% else %} It is an object{% endif %}

{% if {} is object%} It is an object
{% else %} It is NOT an object{% endif %}
```